# how to access phonegap application from server side at any time

Tags: cordova, geolocation, phonegap-build

I had created a `phonegap` application to find the `geolocation`. It works fine in phone and sends the data to php server using ajax.

I have doubt that is it possible to collect current `geolocation` data to php server from phone when needed without opening the application.? ie, when a trigger or something passed from my php server to `phonegap` application it returns the `geolocation` data. (background operation can also used).

If it is possible it helps me when shows with an example.

Thank you.

Comment: check this plugin . may be it will help you to create background service on  android app. 

https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService

Comment: you can not handle any ting from server . you must do same background operation from application

Comment: @jQuery Can you show an example regarding the background operations?. Adding the plugin and accessing it?

Comment: Check this link . 

http://www.tipsfromsiliconvalley.com/2013/07/06/create-a-service-on-android-with-phonegap-application/

Comment: @jQuery I have gone through that link .. but unfortunately lack of my knowledge I was not able to fix it in my code. :(

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a use case for Push notifications, which allow your server to "Push" data to your app, and trigger some behaviour in your app (such as sending back geolocation data).

I've never implemented it, but maybe check out devgirl's phonegap [push notifications tutorial](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/).

Comment: @wiildbeast : Thank you for your response.. Its a valid information for me. I never thought of push notification. But actually am also don't know how to implement it. But give a try